# Calcular curva de roc (sensibilidade e especificidade) com scklear

Tags: python

Olá. Como calculo a curva de roc em python? Já tenho parte do código:

É um *dataset* de tweets que são classificados em inseguro e outros. Estou trabalhando com *cross validation* porque são 400 tweets, 200 para cada classe. Estou utilizando a técnica *k found validation*, onde k=10.

```
# coding=UTF-8

#importando os modulos necessarios e criando as funções para preparar os dados  

import re
from unicodedata import normalize

from nltk import FreqDist
from nltk import tokenize
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import sentiwordnet as swn
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import tree
import sklearn
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def classificarDecisionTree(texto, sentimento):
    print("\nAlgoritmo decision tree")

    #cria um vetor de 1 palavra
    vetor=criarVetor1Palavra()

    #pega a frequência das palavras
    texto_freq=vetor.fit_transform(texto)

    #cria o modelo
    modelo = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

    # Criando uma Confusion Matrix
    avaliarModelo(modelo, texto_freq, sentimento)

#na função a seguir eu pego os vetores com as palavras, ou seja, é         passado o vetor de frequência das palavras já que o modelo não consegue trabalhar com strings  

def criarVetor1Palavra():
        #a linha abaixo traz o vetor de 1 palavra
    return CountVectorizer(analyzer="word")

def avaliarModelo(modelo, texto, sentimento):
    resultados = cross_val_predict(modelo, texto, sentimento, cv=10)

    #calcula acurácia
    acuracia=metrics.accuracy_score(sentimento, resultados)    
    print("acurácia (cross validation): {:.2f}".format(acuracia))
    print("matriz de confusão")
    print("INSEGURO - OUTRO")
    print("{}".format(metrics.confusion_matrix(sentimento, resultados.ravel())))


    #para calcular a curva de roc estou tentando fazer o seguinte:  
    #obs a variável sentimento estou considerando que é equivalente a y usado no exemplo da documentação:  

    fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(sentimento, resultados, pos_label=2)


    auc=metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)

    plot_ROC(fpr, tpr, auc)
    plt.show()

# transforma os textos da classe de sentimentos em 0 para inseguro e 1 para outros

def classeNumerica(df):
    sentimento_map = {"inseguro": 0, "outro": 1}
    return df.map(sentimento_map)


def main():
    #base de tweets classificados
    df=pd.read_csv("tweets_classificados.csv", encoding='ISO-8859-1',     sep=";", header=0)

    # pega 200 inseguros e 200 outros
    inseguros=df[df['sentimento']=="inseguro"]
    inseguros=inseguros.head(200)
    outros=df[df['sentimento']=="outro"]
    outros=outros.head(200)

    #concatena os dois dataframes
    dfn=inseguros.append(outros, ignore_index=True)


    #transforma a coluna sentimento de string para número
    dfn['sentimento']=classeNumerica(dfn['sentimento'])

    classificarDecisionTree(dfn['texto'], dfn['sentimento'])

#função a seguir retirada da resposta a baixo
def plot_ROC(falsePositiveRate, truePositiveRate, areaUnderCurve):
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.set_size_inches(15, 5)
    rocCurve = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)

    rocCurve.plot(falsePositiveRate, truePositiveRate, color = 'darkgreen',
    lw = 2, label = 'ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % areaUnderCurve)
    rocCurve.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color = 'navy', lw = 1, linestyle = '--')
    rocCurve.grid()
    plt.xlim( [0.0, 1.0] )
    rocCurve.set_xticks( np.arange( -0.1, 1.0, 0.1 ))
    plt.ylim( [0.0, 1.05])
    rocCurve.set_yticks( np.arange( 0, 1.05, 0.1 ) )
    plt.xlabel( 'False Positive Rate' )
    plt.ylabel( 'True Positive Rate' )
    plt.title( 'ROC' )
    rocCurve.legend( loc = "lower right" )
    return plt

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Para desenhar a curva ROC, eu primeiro importo essas libraries:

```
# importe suas outras libraries, tipo:  import numpy as np

# para calcular a ROC
from sklearn import metrics

# para desenhar a ROC
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Depois declaro essa função.

```
def plot_ROC( falsePositiveRate, truePositiveRate, areaUnderCurve ):
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.set_size_inches( 15, 5 )
    rocCurve = fig.add_subplot( 1, 2, 1 )

    rocCurve.plot( falsePositiveRate, truePositiveRate, color = 'darkgreen',
             lw = 2, label = 'ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % areaUnderCurve )
    rocCurve.plot( [0, 1], [0, 1], color = 'navy', lw = 1, linestyle = '--' )
    rocCurve.grid()
    plt.xlim( [0.0, 1.0] )
    rocCurve.set_xticks( np.arange( -0.1, 1.0, 0.1 ) )
    plt.ylim( [0.0, 1.05] )
    rocCurve.set_yticks( np.arange( 0, 1.05, 0.1 ) )
    plt.xlabel( 'False Positive Rate' )
    plt.ylabel( 'True Positive Rate' )
    plt.title( 'ROC' )
    rocCurve.legend( loc = "lower right" )
    return plt
```

E depois de declarar, eu uso a função assim:

```
# Y_test é o vetor dos valores com os quais você quer testar a previsão
# Y_probas é obtido com Y_probas = dt.predict_proba( X_test ) 
# Y_probas é o array contendo probabilidades da previsão ser 
# positiva no nível das folhas da sua árvore de decisão
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve( Y_test.values, Y_probas[:,1] )

plot_ROC( fpr, tpr, auc )
plt.show()
```

O exemplo é meio forçado, mas espero que seja útil.

Comment: o dt em # Y_probas é obtido com Y_probas = dt.predict_proba( X_test ) seria a variável com o tipo do modelo treinado?

Comment: dt é a arvore de decisão depois dela treinada com a instrução a seguir:  

    bdt = AdaBoostClassifier( ... varios parametros ...)  
    # no meu caso usei o AdaBoost que gera uma arvore com boosting  

    dt = bdt.fit( X_train, Y_train )

Comment: editei a pergunta para ficar melhor nos exclarecimentos. Não consegui plotar utilizando a função da sua resposta. Revisa, por favor.

Comment: E se você mudar a chamada do método para:

metrics.roc_curve( sentimento, resultados[:,1] ) 

?

Também pode tentar metrics.roc_curve( sentimento.values, resultados[:,1] )